# Any way to four tabs opened as in the old MDI way in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I seem to recall that way back in VS 2005 you could open up four documents, for example, and have them laid out in four quadrants.

Is this at all possible for VS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2013 supports tab groups (tab context menu - New Horizontal/Vertical Tab Group) and floating tabs/tab groups (tab context menu - Float/Float All).

To create four quadrants, you can create an additional vertical tab group in the main VS window + two vertical tab groups in a floating tabs window and position the floating tabs window below the main VS window.

Comment: I guess that works (well it does, I tried it), but it seems a poor fix for something that seems useful for development. Essentially you are splitting out a tab group by floating it, then making the VS window take up 1/2 of the space (horizontally or vertically) of your entire actual screen. If you know, why is this no longer supported? I assume because there is no way to quad windows in actual Windows now (what, since Vista?).

Comment: As a follow-up to anyone reading this, getting a multi-monitor set up definitely helps (expand the desktop in the Display settings window). And actually, it's better to have the main VS window off to the right, and then two floating windows on the left (or vice versa) - just split the main window as well. But with multi-displays (at 2560x1440), I am able to have many MANY VS Windows floating and displayed across 3 screens. Awesome way to multi-task and view different code pages.